# progressDialog didn't show with several views in one activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I created 3 views in one activity depending on the process of the workflow.
i.e. viewA->viewB->viewC, then on viewC, when I do HTTP-POST(using AsyncTask), show progress dialog. 
I tried 2 ways to show progress dialog:

1. using runOnUiThread() to show progressDialog, it didn't show.
2. write show progressDialog code in AsyncTask. Make progress dialog show in onPreExecute() and dismiss in onPostExecute(), it shows after doinbackground task, and onPostExecute() didn't execute as well.

Anyone can help?

Thanks

sam

Here is the main activity code:

```
 public void setA(){
    setContentView(R.layout.a_fm);
    Button aNextBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.aNextBtn);
    aNextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
 public void setB(){
    setContentView(R.layout.b_fm);
    Button bNextBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bNextBtn);
    bNextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
 public void setC(){
    setContentView(R.layout.c_fm);
    Button cNextBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cNextBtn);
    cNextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.aNextBtn:
                setB();
                break;
    case R.id.bNextBtn:
                setB();
                break;
    case R.id.cNextBtn:
                postmsg();
                break;
       }
    }
    public void postmsg(final Info info)
{
    postDialog=new ProgressDialog(AssistFm.this);
    postDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_sending));
    postDialog.show();
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            send_online=sendlogtowebservice(info);
            SEND_COUNT++;
            if (send_online)
            {
                postDialog.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(A_activity.this);
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_success));  
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sendmsg_title)); 
                builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();           
                        setA();
                        SEND_COUNT=0;
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();    
            }
            else 
            {  
                postDialog.dismiss();
                if (SEND_COUNT<SEND_COUNT_MAX)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(A_activity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_retry));  
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sendmsg_title)); 
                    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();       
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            postmsg(info);
                            SEND_COUNT++;
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                }
                else 
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(AssistFm.this);
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_error));  
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sendmsg_title)); 

                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            setA();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

 }
 private boolean sendlogtowebservice(Info info) {
    boolean isTrue = false;
    int result_code = 0;
    Object []param = new Object[3];  
    HttpResponse response = null;    
    String result_str;
    try {   
        String sURL=url;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();        
        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> paierList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        paierList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("person_firstname", info.person_firstname)); 
        paierList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("person_lastname", info.person_lastname)); 
        paierList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("person_mobile", info.person_mobile)); 

        param[0] = sURL;  
        param[1] = paierList;  
        param[2] = client;  
        AsyncTask<Object, Object, HttpResponse> res  = new HttpReqTask().execute(param);
        response = (HttpResponse) res.get();  
        result_code=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        result_str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        if ( result_str.equals("00"))
        {
            isTrue = true;
        }
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {  
        Log.e("HttpAPI.callHttpPost()", "Error", e);  
    }  
    return isTrue;

};
```

Here is the HTTP-POST AsyncTask code:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

 import android.os.AsyncTask;


 public class HttpReqTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, HttpResponse>{

  @Override  
  protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Object... params){  
    String url = (String)params[0];  
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> paierList  = (ArrayList<NameValuePair>)params[1];  
    HttpClient httpclient  = (HttpClient)params[2];  

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);  
    HttpResponse response = null;  
     try {  
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paierList, HTTP.UTF_8));  
        response = httpclient.execute(request);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        throw new RuntimeException(e);  
    }  
    return response;  
}  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No one know how this happened?

I changed the AsyncTask to below, the progress dialog just show a flush away when it is trying to dismiss the progress dialog.

```
public class HttpReqTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, HttpResponse>{
private Context mCtx;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public HttpReqTask(Context  context){     
    myLog.i("HttpReqTask constructor, before show dialog!");  
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mCtx);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Your progress dialog message...");
            progressDialog.show();  
            myLog.i("HttpReqTask constructor finish, start show dialog!");  
}

@Override  
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Object... params){  
    myLog.i("do in background execute");  
    String url = (String)params[0];  
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> paierList  = (ArrayList<NameValuePair>)params[1];  
    HttpClient httpclient  = (HttpClient)params[2];  
    String s=null;  
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);  
    HttpResponse response = null;  
     try {  
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paierList, HTTP.UTF_8));  
        response = httpclient.execute(request); 
        //add for longer process time.
        for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        {
            s="a";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        throw new RuntimeException(e);  
    }  
     myLog.i("finish in background execute");  
    return response;  
}  

@Override    
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {     
    myLog.i("HttpReqTask onPostExecute(), before dismiss dialog!");  
    if (progressDialog!=null) progressDialog.dismiss();      
    myLog.i("HttpReqTask onPostExecute(), after dismiss dialog!");  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems no one knows the answer...
Under my research, I can make the progessDialog shown by creating a new thread, however the AlertDialog in the new thread, can not be shown now...

```
    public void postmsg(final OnlineHistoryInfo info)
{
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(mActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_sending));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
    myLog.i("dialog show!");        
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                myLog.i("new thread: run!");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                send=sendlogtowebservice(info);
                //send_online=true;
                SEND_COUNT++;

            }
            finally
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
               if (send)
                {
                    myLog.i("send:true!");
                    new DataRule(AssistFm.this).saveOnlineHistory(info);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(mActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_success));  
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sendmsg_title)); 
                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            setA();
                            SEND_COUNT=0;
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();    
                }
                else 
                {  
                    myLog.i("send:false!");
                    if (SEND_COUNT<SEND_COUNT_MAX)
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(mActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_retry));  
                        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sendmsg_title)); 
                        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();       
                            }
                        });

                        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                postmsg(info);
                                SEND_COUNT++;
                            }
                        });
                        builder.create().show();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(mActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_sendmsg_error));  
                        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.sendmsg_title)); 

                        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                setA();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.create().show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();



}//postmsg() finish
```